# How to get column and row count for a table in codede ui?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to get row and colun numbers for a table but can not do it.

here is my table

WinTable uIG1Table = this.UIProMANAGEWindow.UIMachineListWindow.UIG1Window.UIG1Table;

First I used methods I have seen in this link but it did not work
http://executeautomation.com/blog/storetableinlist/

```
   int rowCount = uIG1Table.RowCount;
   int colCount = uIG1Table.ColumnCount;
```

I searched for WinTable API and I tried to use API methods. Since there is no columng structures, I used ColumnHeaders for column counting , both row and column brings me 0. Whata should I do ?

```
        int rowCount = uIG1Table.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = uIG1Table.ColumnHeaders.Count;

        MessageBox.Show(rowCount.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(colCount.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching all rows on the window using following code example:

```
internal UITestControlCollection GetGridRows()
{
    var winSearchResults = FindWindowSearchResults();// this can be any WinWindow object

    WinRow gridRows = new WinRow(winSearchResults);

    gridRows.SearchProperties.Add(WinRow.PropertyNames.Name, "Row ", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);// in case of my AUT, the rows name property had "Row " at start
    gridRows.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);

    return gridRows.FindMatchingControls();

}
```

Once you have a row object, you can get cell count through cells property as below:

```
rowFromGrid.Cells
```

Comment: Actually I can get rows, but not headers. I used getRow and tried row 0 but bring first row of the data, not header row.

Comment: I've done this in an application which I automated recently, let me try to get row headers in that case. I guess the cell objects do contain the name of the column they belong to. Try Debug.WriteLine(cell.ToString()) to see details.

Comment: I havent tried your solution bcos I dont know how to apply it. Shall I add it in designer code ? I don not use internal defiitions normaly.  btw, Get row this gives me first fow, not header. Row header, get column etc didnt worked for me.             WinTable uIG1Table = this.UIProMANAGEWindow.UITechnicianReportWindow.UIG1Window.UIG1Table;
            WinRow dataGridrow = uIG1Table.GetRow(0);

Comment: I often use Debug.WriteLine(control.ToString()); to get more information about nasty controls. Try that too with children of row... Maybe just do a foreach on dataGridrow.GetChildren() ...